# CK Editor not pasting the source format eg: paragraph(line) breaks

Tags: ckeditor

I'm copying a document which is in word format and pasting it in ckeditor. But after pasting the line breaks are missing.

Comment: Unfortunate happenings. Do you have any question?

Comment: Yes, I'm also facing another issue with CK Editor after upgrading from 4.7.1 to 4.9.2. The tool bar in the editor is missing and also the tab key doesn't work. Are there any configuration changes that I have to make. Thank you so much.